# When location permission is allowWhenInUse application lifecycle state changes constantly (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, location

My application is requesting location getCurrentLocation every 3 second. So when permission asked, user choses allowWhenInUse, then everytime location fetched android asks for permission showing dialog. If user press "ContinueWithAllowWhenInUse and dont ask again", then my app recieves inactive => resumed, inactive => resumed , repetative states, it feels like Android is still requesting that permission but does not show user and automatically closes it,which triggers app lifecycle state change. As i know inactive can be called when Activity of application is currently not at top, and i think that permission dialog is making it that way. Any thoughs of how to avoid this lifecycle event changes?

Comment: Any solutions found?